# Can't Configure Remote Access of Docker Host

Tags: windows, docker

I did a successful [Docker for Windows install](https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/) on two Windows machines (Windows 10 and Windows 7 x64 SP1).  I can successfully perform administration duties of the docker hosts through terminal services (RDP) or through Powershell remoting.

However, the Docker documentation indicates that the Docker Host offers its own RESTful [remote api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) for administration.  I would like to use this API.  The problem is that in all the examples given in the documentation, the client invocations (via `curl`) are physically on the same box as the Docker Host.  In other words they are not actually *remote* and, unfortunately, the steps to adapt to a remote scenario are not obvious.

For example, consider this command taken straight from the documentation:

> curl --insecure --cert ~/.docker/cert.pem --key ~/.docker/key.pem https://YOUR_VM_IP:2376/images/json

Obviously I need the `YOUR_VM_IP` to proceed. So on both of my Windows boxes I type `docker-machine ls`.  I discover that on *both* the physical Windows machines the address for the Docker Host is `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`.

Oops.  They can't *both* have the same IP address.  Obviously the VirtualBox NAT address is local to the VM in both cases.

This is the primary issue.  I'd like to know how to expose an externally visible Docker Host IP address so that I can actually perform *remote* adminstration.

Possibly this issue is less about Docker and more about VirtualBox.  There are several network interfaces and networking modes that the Docker Host VM could be configured with (e.g. NAT, Bridge, Internal, Host Only.  Perhaps some combination would allow the IP of the Docking Host VM to be exposed.

Or not?  Another possibility is that I'm simply misunderstanding what Docker means by "remote API".  Perhaps "remote" simply means that I don't need to directly SSH into the Docker Host, *from the host machine*, in order to perform administration.  However, I don't think I'm misunderstanding - particularly when I see quotes like this:

> By default, the daemon can only accept local connections over a Unix domain socket.
>   Taken from: [Docker Machine Basics](http://blog.codefresh.io/docker-machine-basics/)

Yes, I have certainly discovered that "by default" it is indeed local.  Now I just need to know how to make it non-local, so that I can provide *remote* administration.  I've found no documentation for this anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found no documentation for this anywhere.

Well, it's probably because "docker on windows" is just a hack intended only for local development on a single box.

Everyone running Docker in production (i.e. people who need multiple boxes) just run Docker directly on Linux with no extra VMs. All the orchestration technologies (Kubernetes, etc) assume the Docker server has a routeable IP address.

> Possibly this issue is less about Docker and more about VirtualBox.

Correct. You can "fix" your problem by [exposing your VM's port 2376](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/panamax-ui/wiki/How-To%3A-Port-Forwarding-on-VirtualBox) to your network. You may also have to allow that port in your Windows firewall too.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: If you are using Windows server 2016, you can try enabling remote with help from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/management/manage_remotehost)

Hope the details of [Issue 109](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet/issues/109) on Microsoft Docker.Dotnet helps

Extract from the above link is as below

Docker for Windows uses a named pipe `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine` to access the REST API. You have to map the pipe to a tcp port.

This can be done with [socat](https://www.heise.de/download/product/socat-80978/download):

`socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork PIPE:\\.\pipes\docker_engine`

After running socat map, you can connect using

`tcp://localhost:2375`

More info on this issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32733#u=1470082504230).

Let me know if it helps